# Stop tag completion from stealing cursor focus

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, autocomplete

How often does this happen to you?

1. Edit a question
2. Change a tag
3. Hit tab and type "tags" in the edit summary box
4. Notice that the tag autosearch has stolen back your cursor so you just typed "tags" in the tags textbox

Can the tag autosearch please stop stealing my cursor?

(btw, what is it called?  Autosearch isn't right... autocomplete isn't right... tag suggestor??)

Comment: "Typing of the Dead" helps to recognize this earlier :}

Comment: The problem is that I'm a touch typist, so by the time I'm hitting tab I'm already not paying attention to the screen (tabedit tagsenter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a similar suggestion a while back on uservoice, but it was declined at the time.  I'll reproduce it here since it is similar to (but not exactly the same as) your suggestion.

---

**[Tag suggestions tooltip steals focus when dismissed](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/102248-tag-suggestions-tooltip-steals-focus-when-dismissed)**

> 1. Start creating a new question.
> 2. In the "Tags" box, type "java".
>      => The suggestions tooltip appears, showing "java", "javascript", etc.
> 3. Click in the main edit area (where you would actually type the question).
>
> Expected: Focus goes to the question area so I can type my question.
>
> Actual: Focus goes to the question area very briefly, then the the tag suggestions tooltip disappears, and when it disappears it gives focus to the tags edit box.

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens when you try to make standard HTML form tags into something fancier!

I tend to just hit escape before tab'ing to the "post question" button.. It cancels the tag auto-completion if it's open, and doesn't break anything if not.

Answer (score 2):

InTagiSense? IntelliTag?

And yes, I know exactly the problem, and it's irked me for some time too. +1

Answer (score 1):

Can't repro this with the current (new, recently improved) tag editor so I am marking it complete.

Comment: awesome, seems to fix the related problem i mentioned in my comment above.